# Does "to John and Henry" mean to each separately, or to both together?

Tags: word-order, conjunctions, ambiguity

> a. She gave John and Henry seventy dollars.
>
> b. She gave John and Henry a knife and a flashlight.
>
> c. She gave twenty dollars to John and Henry.
>
> d. She gave a knife and a flashlight to John and Henry.

Can we tell if

1. John and Henry each received seventy dollars/a knife and a flashlight

or if

2. John and Henry together received seventy dollars/a knife and a flashlight

?

I asked [a similar question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/164083) a couple of days ago, but I think these sentences are
different from those in that question.

Answer (score 1):

These statements are vague enough that we can not definitely state which happened.  Either of your two options could have happened.

Comment: The statements are not vague.  "She gave twenty dollars to John and Henry," compounds J & H into one entity.  That single entity, J & H, was given twenty dollars.  She is out a net of twenty dollars.

Answer (score 1):

If you combine your subjects, John and Henry, into a compound singular entity referred to as John and Henry, then the amount of money you give them is given to compound singular entity.  You could be more clear.

> She gave John and Henry twenty dollars each. = She gave John twenty dollars and Henry twenty dollars.  She paid out forty dollars.
>
> She gave John and Henry a total of twenty dollars. = She gave John and Henry twenty dollars.  She paid out twenty dollars.